# A problem on $Z$-valued functions, where $Z$ is a Banach space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$, $Y$ Banach spaces, $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ the space of linear bounded operators from $X$ to $Y$, if $f:(0,T)\to \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is a continuous function and for every $t \in (0,T)$ the function $g:(0,t)\to X$ is also continuous, can we conclude that the function
$$
F:(0,t)\times (0,T) \to Y
$$
$$
(s,t)  \mapsto  f(t-s)(g(s))
$$
is also continuous?

Comment: $f(t-s) \circ g(s) = f(t-s)(g(s))$?

Comment: @azif00 Yes, exactly

Comment: why not just say $g:(0,T)\to X$ is continuous? why phrase the hypothesis in such a round-about way? Also, why is the domain of $F$ changing? Do you instead mean $F:U\to Y$, where $U=\{(s,t)\in (0,T)\times (0,T)\,:\, 0<s<t\}$, which is a nice open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo really g is continuous, that was a writing mistake. Regarding the domain you are also right, it is exactly this region you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume the conditions I mentioned in the comments otherwise it's not even clear how you can talk about continuity when the domain itself is changing.

Consider the evaluation map $\text{ev}:L(X,Y)\times X\to Y$, $\text{ev}(T,x):=T(x)$. You can easily verify this is a bounded bilinear map, and hence continuous. Your map is just a composition $F(s,t)=\text{ev}\bigg(f(t-s),g(s)\bigg)$, and hence is continuous on the set $U$. To be even more explicit, it is the composition $(s,t)\mapsto (f(t-s),g(s))$ (a mapping into a product space) with the evaluation map.

Comment: I agree with your objection that the problem is needlessly-complicatedly formulated... :) ... but I do see this problem occurring quite often with "abstract analysis". Beginners don't reliably succeed in cutting to the heart of the issue, etc. :)

Comment: Good, thank you very much.